# Reversing the input and output of an optimization in R

Tags: r, function, optimization

Maybe this is too simple of a question. But below I'm showing an optimization in which `df` and `q` are the input and `ncp` is the output.

I'm wondering how to reverse this optimization such that I can input `q` and `ncp` (i.e., `ncp` currently is output), and instead get `df` as the output?

```
df = 30 ; q = 2

f <- function (ncp, alpha, q, df){
abs(suppressWarnings(pt(q = q, df = df, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE)) - alpha)
}

sapply(c(.025, .975),
 function(x)optimize(f, interval = c(-20, 20), alpha = x, q = q, df = df)[[1]])

 # [1] -0.03931343  4.00808666  # Current output `ncp`, but want to become input#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Map(optimise,c(f),ncp=c(-0.03931343,4.00808666),alpha=c(.025, .975),q=q,interval=list(c(0,50)))
[[1]]
[[1]]$minimum
[1] 29.9967

[[1]]$objective
[1] 4.711409e-09


[[2]]
[[2]]$minimum
[1] 30.01264

[[2]]$objective
[1] 1.349743e-09

mapply(optimise,c(f),ncp=c(-0.03931343,4.00808666),alpha=c(.025, .975),q=q,interval=list(c(0,50)))[1,]
[[1]]
[1] 29.9967

[[2]]
[1] 30.01264
```